# Problems with Imagick and PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick

Hy, i have this function:

```
function process_pdf( $file ) {
    if( $file['type'] === 'application/pdf' ) {

        // Get the parent post ID, if there is one
        if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
            $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];

            $filename = $file[ 'name' ];
            $filename_wo_extension = basename( $filename, ".pdf" );

            $im = new Imagick();
            $im->setResolution(300, 300);
            $im->setBackgroundColor('white');
            $im->readimage( $file[ 'tmp_name' ] );
            $im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
            $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
            $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
            $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
            $pages = $im->getNumberImages();

            $attachments_array = array();

            // iterate over pages of the pdf file
            for($p = 1; $p <= $pages; $p++){
                $im->setIteratorIndex( $p - 1 );
                $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
                $im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
                $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
                $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
                $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
                
                $page_title = get_the_title($post_id);

                $filename_neu = $page_title .'_pagina_'. $p .'.jpg';

                // upload new image to wordpress
                // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment
                $upload_file = wp_upload_bits($filename_neu, null, $im);
                if (!$upload_file['error']) {

                    $attachment = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename_neu),
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_parent' => $post_id,
                        'post_status' => 'inherit'
                    );

                    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'] );

                    if (!is_wp_error( $attachment_id )) {
                        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                        $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload_file['file'] );
                        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
                        $attachments_array[] = $attachment_id;

                    }
                }
            }
           // add new images to a gallery (advanced custom fields plugin)
            // http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/
           //update_field( 'field_62a736b215b2f', $attachments_array, $post_id );
          $im->destroy();
       }
    }

    return $file;

}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'process_pdf' );
```

when i upload PDF file on wordpress all page is converted to JPG and upload in site.

Function work and do what i need, but problem appear when i upload THIS File:
https://easyupload.io/o6hsk3

for understand where is the problem:
i try to compare this file with another;
i upload a big pdf file with more resolution, page.

All work good, but this pdf file not work:(

have any ideea why?

Comment: if PDF file is to large in DPI , or if i set a large resolution for image function crash

Comment: after PDF file is uploaded 100%, CPU on server is increase to 100% and server crash,  probably need to optimize this CPU OVERLOAD